# ASP.Net Core 3.1 razor page show error for list of employee

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to convert Blazor example to ASP.Net Core Razor page for learning purpose but i am getting bunch of errors in Employees.cshtml page and Employees.cshtml.cs where i am trying to call data.

I am simply trying to show data on this page, i am not sure how & where to define functions call data. I not using WebAPI.

I am also trying to find simple CRUD example related to asp.net core 3.1 so that i know how flow works later on i can convert same using dapper etc..

I have no prior experience of MVC or Core

UPDATE: I had few error which have been resolved but only error i am getting when running is in programe.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

**error message**

> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service
>   descriptor 'ServiceType: RazorCore31.Data.IEmployeeService Lifetime:
>   Scoped ImplementationType: RazorCore31.Data.EmployeeService': Unable
>   to resolve service for type 'RazorCore31.Data.SqlDbContext' while
>   attempting to activate 'RazorCore31.Data.EmployeeService'.
>
> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
>   constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
>   'ServiceType: RazorCore31.Data.IEmployeeService Lifetime: Scoped
>   ImplementationType: RazorCore31.Data.EmployeeService': Unable to
>   resolve service for type 'RazorCore31.Data.SqlDbContext' while
>   attempting to activate 'RazorCore31.Data.EmployeeService'.)'

**EmployeeService.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RazorCore31.Models;

namespace RazorCore31.Data
{
    public class EmployeeService: IEmployeeService
    {


        private readonly SqlDbContext _dbContext;

        public EmployeeService(SqlDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        public async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployees()
        {
            return await _dbContext.Employees.ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task<bool> CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            employee.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            _dbContext.Add(employee);
            try
            {
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return true;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        public async Task<Employee> SingleEmployee(string id)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Employees.FindAsync(id);
        }
        public async Task<bool> EditEmployee(string id, Employee employee)
        {
            if (id != employee.Id)
            {
                return false;
            }

            _dbContext.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
        public async Task<bool> DeleteEmployee(string id)
        {
            var patient = await _dbContext.Employees.FindAsync(id);
            if (patient == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            _dbContext.Employees.Remove(patient);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }

        Task<List<Employee>> IEmployeeService.GetEmployees()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

**IEmployeeService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RazorCore31.Models;

namespace RazorCore31.Data
{
    public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployees();
        Task<bool> CreateEmployee(Employee employee);
        Task<bool> EditEmployee(string id, Employee employee);
        Task<Employee> SingleEmployee(string id);
        Task<bool> DeleteEmployee(string id);
    }
}
```

**Employee.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using RazorCore31.Data;

namespace RazorCore31.Models
{
    public class Employee 
    {

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is RRRequired")]
        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Name is too long.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Department { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Company { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string City { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Employees.cshtml**

```
@page
@model RazorCore31.EmployeesModel
@using RazorCore31.Data
@using RazorCore31.Models
@using System.Collections.Generic
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Employees";
}

<h1>Employees list</h1>

<p>List of Employee</p>

@if (employees == null)
{
    <p>Loading page...</p>
}
else
{
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>EmpName"</th>
                <th>L["EmpDepartment"]</th>
                <th>L["EmpDesignation"]</th>
                <th>L["EmpCompany"]</th>
                <th>L["EmpCity"]</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var employee in employees)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@employee.Name</td>
                    <td>@employee.Department</td>
                    <td>@employee.Designation</td>
                    <td>@employee.Company</td>
                    <td>@employee.City</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href='/editemployee/@employee.Id'>Edit</a>
                        <a href='/deleteemployee/@employee.Id'>Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

**Employees.cshtml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using RazorCore31.Models;
using RazorCore31.Data;

namespace RazorCore31
{
    public class EmployeesModel : PageModel
    {
       //public  List<Employee> employees ;

        private List<Employee> _empList;

        public void empRepository()
        {
            //_empList = Data.EmployeeService.
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public Task getEmployeesAsync()
        {
            _empList = EmployeeService.GetEmployees();
           // return _empList;
        }

    }
}

Startup.cs

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
    ///services.AddSingleton<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();


}
```

**ERROR in Program.cs**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

[image]

> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service
>   descriptor 'ServiceType: RazorCore31.Data.IEmployeeService Lifetime:
>   Scoped ImplementationType: RazorCore31.Data.EmployeeService': Unable
>   to resolve service for type 'RazorCore31.Data.SqlDbContext' while
>   attempting to activate 'RazorCore31.Data.EmployeeService'.
>
> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
>   constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
>   'ServiceType: RazorCore31.Data.IEmployeeService Lifetime: Scoped
>   ImplementationType: RazorCore31.Data.EmployeeService': Unable to
>   resolve service for type 'RazorCore31.Data.SqlDbContext' while
>   attempting to activate 'RazorCore31.Data.EmployeeService'.)'

**ERROR MESSAGES (This error is resolved based on `@TanvirArjel` solution )**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Write your `EmployeesModel` as follows:

```
public class EmployeesModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;

    public EmployeesModel(IEmployeeService employeeService)
    {
        _employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    public List<Employee> EmployeeList; // <-- Here is the EmployeeList property

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        EmployeeList = await _employeeService.GetEmployees(); // <-- Populate EmployeeList here
    }
}
```

Then in the view:

```
@page
@model RazorCore31.EmployeesModel
@using RazorCore31.Data
@using RazorCore31.Models
@using System.Collections.Generic
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Employees";
}

<h1>Employees list</h1>

<table class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>EmpName"</th>
            <th>L["EmpDepartment"]</th>
            <th>L["EmpDesignation"]</th>
            <th>L["EmpCompany"]</th>
            <th>L["EmpCity"]</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var employee in Model.EmployeeList) //<-- Here it is
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@employee.Name</td>
                <td>@employee.Department</td>
                <td>@employee.Designation</td>
                <td>@employee.Company</td>
                <td>@employee.City</td>
                <td>
                    <a href='/editemployee/@employee.Id'>Edit</a>
                    <a href='/deleteemployee/@employee.Id'>Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i am getting error for `EmployeeList = _employeeService.GetEmployees(); ` cant implicityly convert type ... `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<RazorCore31.Models.Employee>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<RazorCore31.Models.Employee>'`

Comment: @Learning Okay! Got it and answer has been updated.

Comment: another error when i try to vied employees page `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'RazorCore31.Data.EmployeeService' while attempting to activate 'RazorCore31.EmployeesModel'.

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)`

Comment: @Learning Please check the updated answer. I have replaced `EmployeeService` with `IEmployeeService`

Comment: This generates another error `employeeService` _employeeService = employeeService;...

cant implicitly convert type

Comment: Please check my answer again. You did not replace properly.

Comment: Error are gone but ` services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();` generate another error `AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: RazorCore31.Data.IEmployeeService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: RazorCore31.Data.EmployeeService': Unable to resolve service for type 'RazorCore31.Data.SqlDbContext' while attempting to activate 'RazorCore31.Data.EmployeeService'.)`

Comment: I converted  service to singelton but error again `services.AddSingleton<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();`

Comment: Don't make it  singleton. Make both `EmployeeService` and `SqlDbContext ` as scoped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208053/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-learning).